# Opencart admin cron job

Tags: php, cron, opencart, payment-gateway

How can I add a cronjob to OpenCart "payment gateway" to update the status of orders that have pending status?

I have InquiryBatch.php (admin/controller/extension/payment/InquiryBatch.php) file that updates the orders status, but I don't know to run it at a scheduled time.

Comment: [batch-file] *A batch file is a text file containing a series of commands that are executed by the command interpreter on MS-DOS, IBM OS/2, or Microsoft Windows systems.*

Comment: I don't have any problems with the file, I just need to run a specific method, for example, every five minutes to update the status of pending orders!

Comment: So you developed a plugin and want to sell it on opencart marketplace but you don't know how cron works?

Comment: yes, I need to add cron code to my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If your web host has cPanel, here's how:
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Cron+Jobs

If you don't have cPanel but you do have SSH access you need to use the Linux crontab -e command.

If you have neither, you can use an external cron service such as EasyCron:
https://www.easycron.com/

Comment: I need to add it in my plugin (in the PHP files)! Is that possible? I don't  need to use any external method.

Comment: Good question. It is possible, you can use the cPanel API if your plugin will be on cPanel and you can use shell_exec in PHP to add it to the crontab if you have access to it but I would advise against this - very few modules do it because it's very unreliable. Far better to provide install instructions that tell the user they must add a cron via their web host.

Comment: I don't have any hosting, I developed a payment gateway plugin and I will upload it to opencart marketplace, I just need to write a cron job inside my plugin, to be executed every hour (for example) to update the status of orders were paid by my payment method! Really thank you anyway :)